# req.target showing undefined - sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I am using req.target to get the controller name and action name whereas sometimes it is showing undefined when i log req.target and my other functionalities are affected as it is based on req.target.

Please help me out to solve this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you say under what conditions `req.target` is empty?

Comment: For loading only the required javascript files for each page , based on the controller and action i am loading the respective javascript files. For this functionality iam using req.target to get controller name and action name. I am using req.target in one of the config files for this functionality. Sometimes req.target is showing undefined and my javascript files are not loaded and throwing error that file is not there . Not able to find why sometimes alone req.target is showing undefined when we log it

Comment: For two or three controllers alone it is showing req.target undefined. For other controllers it is showing the controller and action. Is there any other way to get controller name?

Answer (score 1):

Hy,

If you are using sails > 0.10 you should use req.options instead of req.target 
to get your controller you can use `req.options.controller`and `req.options.action` to get your action :)

Comment: But my sails version is 0.9.7 only

Comment: Thanks. Worked in version 0.12.3. I wish the documentation was clearer.